# Max number of subdirectories in btrfs

Tags: btrfs

Is there a maximum limit to the number of subdirectories in a single directory for btrfs like the 64,000 limit in ext4?

(see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775011/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-subdirectories-allowed-in-ext4)

Answer (score 4):

There is no limit, but you cannot create more then 2^64 directories in total.

---

Btrfs does not have a  specific limit for the content of a directory (neither for files, nor for sub-directories). The content is represented as lists, but its length is not limited. However, each directory will need its own inode. As btrfs uses 64-bit integers, there cannot be more then 2^64 inodes in total. That number defines an upper bound for the number of sub-directories that you can create. For details, see the [design document](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Btrfs_design).

Note that 2^64 is such a high number that for all practical  circumstances, it is unlimited. You will rather run out of disk space until you hit that limit.

Answer (score 3):

If my memory is serving me right, BTRFS doesn't have a subdirectory limit but it has total number of files limit, which is a ridiculously high number of 2^64. I searched google but could not find the document where I saw this from. I think it was an oracle web page. So take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: [wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs) right hand side overview